# How to add testing library to Intellij Idea Create Test pop-up

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, spock, hotkeys

In Intellij Idea when I press CMD+Shift+t I see this:
[image: 1]

After pressing Enter I see new window with possibility to choose test library
[image: 2]

If I need to add here Spock framework, how can I do it?
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
Groovy plugin is enabled, I have latest version of Idea.

Interesting thing that I can run existing Spock tests and everything is working good, the only problem is that I have to create test file manually.

Comment: This question is somewhat off-topic here on Stack Overflow and would better fit on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: Anyway, got try IDEA extension [Spock Framework Enhancements](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7114-spock-framework-enhancements). It provides a few helpful live templates like "spgwt" (Spock given-when-then) and also one intention to create a test, which sadly for me only works in Groovy classes, not Java, despite my main use case being to write Spock tests for Java classes. I think, it was time to open an issue for the plugin: https://github.com/cholick/idea-spock-enhancements/issues/43.

Comment: There's a bug in IDEA with "create test": https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-316239